# Good architecture for passing data to multiple APIs

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, api

- I have a hypothetical scenario where I need to pass data to APIs from multiple different providers, depending on the 'vendor identity' provided by one of the pieces of data.
- If I have the data as objects within an enumerable parent object, what would be a good way to pass the objects to the appropriate API in a reasonably loosely coupled way?
- Even if the API definition was more tightly hardcoded somehow, what would be a good way to actually pass the objects through to the API?
- I'm writing the solution in C# although it's the general architecture that matters not the specific implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would help if you clarified how much difference in APIs there are. eg. Could ytou be using 2 location services where one takes lat/long co-ordinates, and the other XY co-ords; or are they more different like a location service and a pizza-ordering service?

Either way, your best bet is a message passing architecture. You have a broker  or message bus that your main code sends messages to, and the broker decides which API to pass the message on to. Often you will have a facade (or gateway) that sits between the broker and the APIs if there is a fair bit of translation required from the program's data that is sent to the broker and what the API expects to receive.

One benefit of a message broker like this is you can add new APIs dynamically, once they register to receive messages, they will suddenly start to receive them, no code changes required in your client program, assuming you can send the new relevant data.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a good opportunity for message queues.

Queues are good for retrying errors and for keeping things loosely coupled.  For example, the data you're passing could be pushed onto an incoming queue.  Some process would grab it and decide which APIs should receive it, writing it to several outgoing queues.  The outgoing queues when processed pass the data along to the appropriate receiver.  This models the human workflow of workers having in bins and out bins on their desk and delivery workers who get the outgoing paperwork to the right place.